# Upgrade AngularJS to Angular 6 in Cordova App

Tags: angularjs, angular, cordova, hybrid

I have a Cordova app built using Angular 1 i.e. Angular JS. How I can upgrade the app yo latest angular version.

Will it require complete code re-write to TypeScript (TS)??

Comment: https://update.angular.io/ this might help you.

Comment: It only support angular version greater than equal to 2.0

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/upgrade checkout this offical doc

Comment: Yes, i think you will have to rewrite everything and adapt it to the new flow and Angular API

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is not a requirement for writing Angular 2+. However, Angular 2-7 does not have much in common with AngularJS as it doesn't have the same architecture or components. For example, from what i've read about it, AngularJS used a MVC model, Angular2+ does not.

So to answer your question, you will indeed need to rewrite most of your application. Going from Angular 2 to 7 is much easier as not much has changed.